# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS randomly freezes

Tags: ubuntu, crash

I just freshly installed Ubuntu on my ASUS Aspire E15. It's alongside a Windows installation.

Roughly 10 minutes into my boot (maybe longer), everything will just freeze. I can move the mouse but no shortcuts work and no programs respond. I have to hold the power button to turn the computer off, then boot again. I think it may be related to a problem with git. I am trying to git pull in the background.

How would I go about determining what is causing the freezes?

Comment: I won't be able to help you (not a sysadmin and I don't have ubuntu nor asus), but... Have you checked the logs? Are you positive "everything" has frozen? or is it just the desktop environment? After the freeze, can you drop to a command line and investigate? People will not help you if your question basically reads "use a magical crystal ball to supernaturally debug my system on which I will give no useful information" :)

Comment: BTW: doesn't seem likely that's related to git - does it always happen when you use git?

Answer (score 2):

i faced  this problem before  on my ASUS  , it seems that  the problem was on DE i was using Ubuntu MATE after that i installed xfce and the problem ends
i don't know why MATE freezes and what causes this problem 
if you want to install xfce just on your terminl `sudo apt-get install xfce4`
and then logout and on the login screen you can switch between  your current DE
and xfce 
i also advise you to use just simple window manager like openbox 
see that [assemble minimal fast DE](https://www.prahladyeri.com/blog/2016/02/minimal-debian-desktop-setup.html)    it will help you customize your own DE